# Error installing SweetAlert on Laravel through npm

Tags: laravel, npm, sweetalert

When I run $ npm install sweetalert --save-dev

I get

```
"sweetalert": "^1.1.3"
```

saved to my package.json

I run $ npm run dev to compile the app.js file with webpack which loads successfully

But when I try to use the module eg

```
<script>
  sweetAlert("Hello world!");
</script>
```

I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: sweetAlert is not defined`

I have also tried to reference the js and css files in my header with combinations of "./node_" and "../node_" and "/node_" and so on

```
<script src="node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css">
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did the below answer solve your issue or do you need more help with it? If it does solve your problem please would mark it as correct?

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add `require('sweetalert')` to your `app.js` file e.g.:

```
require('./bootstrap');

require('sweetalert');
```

Then run `npm run dev` again.

Lastly, just make sure `<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>` is above

```
<script>
  sweetAlert("Hello world!");
</script>
```

**NB** The above assumes you have not changed the paths/filenames that come out-of-the-box with laravel.

Hope this helps!